# Is Japanese word segmentation on web sites considered the norm and completely acceptable?

Tags: unicode, internationalization

First off, I don't speak/read Japanese, making this a bit tricky.

But in researching Japanese internationalization for websites, I started looking into some reportedly popular news sites (Yomiuri.co.jp and Asahi.com) and it doesn't look like they have any solutions implemented to prevent word segmentation. The browser is doing the basic kinsoku shori with punctuation/brackets/etc, but the sites both have flexible layouts and you can watch as most characters wrap individually.

Is this normal/understood/accepted? Seems awfully awkward.

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinsoku Shori as well as the other [CJK line-breaking rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_breaking_rules_in_East_Asian_language) are the responsibility of the layout engine, not the document itself.

Answer (score 2):

I do not get your question. As far as I know CJK languages do not have concept of word-spacing and you can split the lines almost anywhere.

Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap#Word_wrapping_in_text_containing_Chinese.2C_Japanese.2C_and_Korean

Comment: The rules are [fairly well defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_breaking_rules_in_East_Asian_language).

Comment: Thanks, to add further context, I received some feedback from a translator regarding this string: "パスワードを忘れた場合" where the final character "合" was wrapping to the next line due to a fixed layout. She reported that "場合" is one word and "合" should not be sitting by itself, which sent me down the rabbit hole. I have since discussed this with a couple Japanese software engineers (read: technical, which I now presume the translator is not) who agree with your all completely, that this is normal, acceptable, and to be expected. Thanks again!

Comment: This is incorrect. Korean (what the "K" in "CJK" stands for) does use spaces between words, but Chinese and Japanese do not.

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle of kinsoku is that splitting most words most of the time is perfectly acceptable.